# How to change the alignment of a radio input with textarea in html5?

Tags: html

I want to put a radio button right next to a text box as per the following:

```
 <input type="radio" name="myRadioButton" id="firstRadioButton">
 <textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
```

When textarea grows in width, the radio button aligns with the bottom of it.  How do I make the radio button align with the top of the text area?

Comment: This is the default behavior of these elements, please be more specific about how the two elements should be positioned.

Comment: I want to change the default behavior in a way that the radio button (or any other element, like a label) aligns to the top of the text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `vertical-align` CSS property:

```css
input[type="radio"]
{
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="myRadioButton" id="firstRadioButton">
<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can position the elements relatively inside their parent and give them a specific float direction. I put two sets of HTML elements so we can see the radio on both sides.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}

textarea {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="myRadioButton" id="firstRadioButton">
<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>


<textarea id="myTextArea2"></textarea>
<input type="radio" name="myRadioButton2" id="secondRadioButton">
```

Comment: I wouldn't use floats for something like this. It can mess with the dom and requires more code to clear the elements after

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by css. with vertical align-top. I would make a class like this

```
.align-top{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

and i would add this class in any element i want this behavior.

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadioButton" id="firstRadioButton" class="align-top">
<textarea id="myTextArea" class="align-top"></textarea>
```

You dont need the ids  but you can keep them if you want o access the elements individualy through css or js in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can also you `flex` to align-items :

Here is the documentation for proper guidance on how to use flexbox : [Document](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="myRadioButton" id="firstRadioButton">
  <textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
</div>
```

```
.container{
  display:flex;
}
```

Comment: This does it.  However, I have subsequent radio button/textarea groups, and using flex put them all on the same horizontal alignment (instead of subsequent lines).  Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: You can try to use ```flex-direction: column``` on the ```.container``` and see if this helps you